# Generate PDF files with Zend

Tags: zend-framework, fpdf, zend-pdf

Could you help me please to solve my problem. I have to use zend Framework to generate Pdf files. i choose to use FPDF library to do it. When i try to generate Pdf, i get the message below :

%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x???Mn۰ ???,:&? ?s ?h?? ?e6?Ŧ*lː? ?U??[t Ų-ۚD+IC~|󦉄߮ f ??E! ??Q ?'2? 򂮯ڵ?+(ޅfќ@? ~H? ?Ң?I?H? iyƬ( 4???]Ymⳑ񭨷𰽥-??B3??z?I`Z ?La&#1223;?Y?t k%sI???? &#27000;L9?7&#1451;&#1322;???? _?E??$E? ?'?N&#1865;?y?; ,?&#1216;X?? m}&#42169;&#22800;e`?????4ԁ搭Ὤ? ???Ϳ?ꢮ?1?ʮ ,*;A ǐ ny آr ?B?󻊳謐"Ɇ?E ˕ɍ??=ɪ踀Dµ?Ӟصe?޶}_Ĳ? m?,?? hYmx?? Ňy7?G?Č???] my`9Bㆥ?8䣖m[???Ĩ ?? ~??Ѓ1??媵}fo8僀f ]v!?>?iY?p/(Ej??n?????'?c?O??h?$䳹Ӽ¬???\ ?ER)DJ)? ?}?FN?q:?ˊY𴿺㮘? 봐轊 Ø??Йx?͡7?᫘?K???? endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 5 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.7) /CreationDate (D:20120427161022) >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R >> endobj xref 0 8 0000000000 65535 f 0000000725 00000 n 0000000908 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000812 00000 n 0000001012 00000 n 0000001087 00000 n trailer << /Size 8 /Root 7 0 R /Info 6 0 R >> startxref 1136 %%EOF

I searched the web but i haven't find a solution, so i tried to generate my files with Zend_PDF but i got the same message and not a pdf file.
Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not setting your headers correctly, I'm guessing you're using `render()` in Zend_PDF so try adding this in place on your current `render()`

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf', true);
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename=my-file.pdf', true);
$this->getResponse()->setBody($pdf->render());
```

See [Zend Framework PDF problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329302/zend-framework-pdf-problems)

Comment: Thanks Ashley, i added your code but i still get the same message. Below is my code for FPDF     `$pdf = new MesCreations_PDF();  
   $header = array('N° ordre', 'Date envoi', 'Nom du client', 'N° de compte', 'N° contrat', 'Type de produit', 'Durée', 'Montant', 'Nature opération');
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
   $pdf->EtatToPdf($header,$id);
   $pdf->Output();`

Comment: For the test with Zend_PDF this is my code : `$page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$pdf->pages[] = $page; 

// Crée une nouvelle police
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
 
// Applique la police et dessine du texte
$page->setFont($font, 36);
 $page->drawText('Helvetica 36 text string', 60, 500);
// Get PDF document as a string
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf', true);
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename=my-file.pdf', true);
$this->getResponse()->setBody($pdf->render());`

Comment: You're probably outputting some other whitespace or html before you're outputting the pdf. make sure you've got no whitespace or anything before you use that code

Comment: Thanks Ashley! i've found the solution. I disabled the layout with `$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();`